# How to work with a model in viewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem with using MVVM for a Xamarin project.

I can not refresh the user interface if one of my objects in my viewModel is updated (after a PUT request, for example).

Let me explain :

My model :

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

My viewmodel :

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MyObject MyObject { get; private set; }

    public string IdMvvm
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.MyObject.Id != value)
            {
                MyObject.Id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IdMvvm));
            }
        }
        get { return MyObject.Id; }
    }

    public string NameMvvm
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.MyObject.Name != value)
            {
                MyObject.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameMvvm));
            }
        }
        get { return MyObject.Name; }
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PageTitle { get; protected set; }
    LayoutViewModel() {}

    // MVVM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
            return;

        backingField = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
```

MyViewModel is defined as BindingContext for my page
My properties IdMvvm and NameMvvm are bind in Entry in my page in xaml

When I modify an Entry then the value is raised but if my MyModel object changes value, for example update (click on a button) then the value of the different Entry is not updated

Can you help me please? Because it seems that I missed something ...
If you need more explanation, tell me to know

Sorry if my english is not good

Comment: a best approach : MyViewModel doesn't contain Model. Use AutoMapper to map the properties you want to show from Model to ViewModel

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will also look on that side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you change the model, your view is not aware about the change. Update your code so that you explicitly notify property changes when your model changes.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MyObject _myObject;
    public MyObject MyObject 
    { 
       get { return _myObject; }
       private set { _myObject = value; NotifyModelChange(); }
    }

    public string IdMvvm
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.MyObject.Id != value)
            {
                MyObject.Id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IdMvvm));
            }
        }
        get { return MyObject.Id; }
    }

    public string NameMvvm
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.MyObject.Name != value)
            {
                MyObject.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameMvvm));
            }
        }
        get { return MyObject.Name; }
    }

    private void NotifyModelChange()
    {
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IdMvvm));
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameMvvm));
    }
}
```